# Sorting a list based on containing lists

Tags: python

I have to sort a list contianing other lists based on the value of index 0. As it may be clear seeing the example below, i have to sort 'tempdb' based on the years of each nested list, but i have no clue. I am not allowed to import a library like NumPy, etc. so just 'naked' Python code.

Example of a list:

```
tempdb = [
['8-8-2007', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2007'],
['8-8-2015', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2015'],
['30-11-2005', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'nov', '2005'],
['8-8-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'aug', '2006'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2003', '268', 'Anonymized', 'gammaglutamyltranspeptidase', 'nov', '2003'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'melkzuurdehydrogenase -ldh- kinetisch', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'alkalische fosfatase -kinetisch-', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2002', '268', 'Anonymized', 'natrium vlamfotometrisch', 'nov', '2002'],
]
```

This is something I found and already tried, but it did not work for me.

```
sort_on   = lambda pos:     lambda x: x[pos]
tempdb = sorted(tempdb,key=sort_on(1))
```

My goal was to start with the oldest year (ex. 2002) and end with the newest year (ex. 2015)

Comment: Please explain the _"did not work for me"_ part. You already know what failed. Why would the other find out by themselves?

Comment: You can sort by the last value of each sublist: sorted(tempdb,key=lambda l: l[-1])

Comment: `tempdb = sorted(tempdb, key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: @MykolaZotko  does not work --- it is a alphabetical sorting not based on datetimes so `'1-1-3999'` is "less then" `'2-1-1901'`

Comment: You list is no list ... it lacks `,` - '8-8-20015' ...thats faaaar in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime` module to compare dates:

```
from datetime import datetime

tempdb = [
['8-8-2007', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2007'],
['8-8-2015', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2015'],
['30-11-2005', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'nov', '2005'],
['8-8-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'aug', '2006'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2003', '268', 'Anonymized', 'gammaglutamyltranspeptidase', 'nov', '2003'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'melkzuurdehydrogenase -ldh- kinetisch', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'alkalische fosfatase -kinetisch-', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2002', '268', 'Anonymized', 'natrium vlamfotometrisch', 'nov', '2002'],
]

tempdb = sorted(tempdb, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d-%m-%Y'))

for i in tempdb: print(i)
```

#### Output:

```
['30-11-2002', '268', 'Anonymized', 'natrium vlamfotometrisch', 'nov', '2002']
['30-11-2003', '268', 'Anonymized', 'gammaglutamyltranspeptidase', 'nov', '2003']
['30-11-2005', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'nov', '2005']
['8-8-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'aug', '2006']
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'nov', '2006']
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'melkzuurdehydrogenase -ldh- kinetisch', 'nov', '2006']
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'alkalische fosfatase -kinetisch-', 'nov', '2006']
['8-8-2007', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2007']
['8-8-2015', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2015']
```

If you want to sort in the opposite direction add `reverse=True` to the `sorted()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solutiopn would be to sort by the last string of each inner list .. but this will not sort monts/days correctly if a year is identical.

You can use the first element if you split it at `'-'`, convert every number to integer and reverse the result and use that to sort:

```
'8-8-2015' --> [2015,8,8]
```

Code:

```
tempdb = [
['8-8-2007', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2007'],
['8-8-20015', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2015'],
['30-11-2005', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'nov', '2005'],
['8-8-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'aug', '2006'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2003', '268', 'Anonymized', 'gammaglutamyltranspeptidase', 'nov', '2003'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'melkzuurdehydrogenase -ldh- kinetisch', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'alkalische fosfatase -kinetisch-', 'nov', '2006'],
['30-11-2002', '268', 'Anonymized', 'natrium vlamfotometrisch', 'nov', '2002'],
]

s = sorted(tempdb, key = lambda x: list(map(int,reversed(x[0].split('-')))))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
[['30-11-2002', '268', 'Anonymized', 'natrium vlamfotometrisch', 'nov', '2002'], 
 ['30-11-2003', '268', 'Anonymized', 'gammaglutamyltranspeptidase', 'nov', '2003'], 
 ['30-11-2005', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'nov', '2005'], 
 ['8-8-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'aug', '2006'], 
 ['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'ordertarief', 'nov', '2006'], 
 ['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'melkzuurdehydrogenase -ldh- kinetisch', 'nov','2006'],
 ['30-11-2006', '268', 'Anonymized', 'alkalische fosfatase -kinetisch-', 'nov', '2006'],
 ['8-8-2007', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2007'], 
 ['8-8-20015', '268', 'Anonymized', 'aanname laboratoriumonderzoek', 'aug', '2015']]
```

You still gave "invalid" data - f.e. `'8-8-20015'` - thats on you.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to sort by year then by the number in the middle then by the first number in the date:

```
sorted(tempdb, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x[0].split('-')[::-1])))
```

Comment: You can use the last item of the nested list.

Comment: @WaKo what do you mean?

Comment: `x[-1]` in your example

Comment: yeah if all you care about is the year

Comment: According to the question `i have to sort 'tempdb' based on the years of each nested list`

Comment: Well then that's an extra cherry on top I guess

Comment: I was unclear, but indeed meant to sort by day, month and year. But my problem is solved. Thanks to all of you!